# Java Report with charts made by JFreeChart

Tags: java, pdf, report, jfreechart, jfreereport

There is a Java library for creating report (PDF files) using the chart made by JFreeReport? Someone talk me about JFreeReport but I can't find any infos about it. Maybe the JFreeReport project is deprecated?

Comment: Yes, JFreeReport is depricated. Try [JasperReports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jasper Reports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library) claims to be able to report JFreeCharts.

[JFreeChart sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jfreechart/index.html)